# In Java Serialization if a class has multiple objects (composition) then in what order the state will be retrieved?

Tags: java, serialization

if a class is defined like

```
public class A implements java.io.Serializable
{
    Example a;
    Test b;
    Another c;
}
```

while retrieving the state,in which order will it be retrieved?
A's object?
a?
b?
c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you serialise `A` it will be written out as:

- Start of `A`
- `a`
- `b`
- `c`
- End of `A`

Deserialisation reads the stream in the same order that serialisation wrote it. However, the serialised stream is just a sequence of octets and may have `a`, `b` and `c` in a different order (the fields will only ever be assigned at most once).

Further, the objects could have other references to one another. For instance, even if there is no way at runtime that `Test` can reference `Another`, deserialisation of `b` could include the object that is deserialised to `c`.

Comment: Make up your mind. *Either* it is 'written out as a/b/c' *or* it 'may have` a,b,c` in a different order'.

Comment: @EJP It is written out as A/a/b/c/A, but a stream, perhaps created by a different version of the stream or perhaps in vi, may contain the data in the order A/c/b/a/A.

Answer (score 0):

1. Contrary to other answers here, the order isn't specified, other than that base classes precede derived classes.
2. It doesn't matter, as field names are also passed, so the stream is unambiguous.
3. It can be altered by the class itself.
4. Contrary to an answer here, the default constructor for the nearest non-serializable superclass is executed for each object in the stream. In this case, at least four of them.

See the [Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec).

Answer (score -1):

The Order of the Bytecode is important, usually the same order as you write java.

1. a will be loaded.
2. b will be loaded.
3. c will be loaded.
4. if no exceptions have been thrown, place a,b,c
5. execute method readObject if exists.

**Note**: No constructor will be executed!
**Note**: Obfuscatores may change field names.

Comment: `a,b,c` can be in any order, and non-serializable base class constructors are executed: in this case, at least four. -1

Comment: @EJP Please explain. Where do the runtime know whats the arguments for a non-serializable base class constructors? Where does the runtime know what non-serializable base class constructor he need to execute if there are multiple base-class-constructors?